# Representing a multi-affine map as a determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, multilinear-algebra

Given a multi-affine map $f: \mathbb{R}^n \mapsto \mathbb{R}$, is it always possible to represent the function as a determinant? And is there a principled way to generate the matrix if it is possible?

To make a concrete examples, consider the following two functions in 4 variables $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^4$: the cubic function
$$
f(\mathbf{x}) = a_1x_2x_3x_4+a_2x_3x_4x_1+a_3x_4x_1x_2+a_4x_1x_2x_3
$$
and the quadratic form
$$
g(\mathbf{x}) = 
b_{12}x_1x_2 + b_{13}x_1x_3 + b_{14}x_1x_4+b_{23}x_2x_3+b_{24}x_2x_4+b_{34}x_3x_4.\\
$$
Both of them are affine functions of each of the variables. 
Using educated guessing, I was able to find
$$
f(\mathbf{x}) = 
\left|
\begin{matrix}
a_1 & -a_2 & a_3 & -a_4\\
x_1 & x_2 & 0 & 0\\
0 & x_2 & x_3 & 0\\
0 & 0 & x_3 & x_4
\end{matrix}
\right|,
$$
yet I am wondering what other solutions are possible, for example using a symmetric matrix. For the function $g$ I don't see a similarly simple solution. Any pointer to the right keywords would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The right keyword is, unsurprisingly, *determinantal representation* (of a polynomial). This has apparently been a topic of interest in algebraic geometry. A comparatively accessible account on the question of representing the zero set of any polynomial is the paper [Polynomials with and without determinantal representations](http://oldwww.ma.man.ac.uk/raag/preprints/0314.pdf) by Netzer and Thom.

The main points are:
1. Every polynomial in 2 variables has a representation as a determinant;
2. In general this is not true for more than 2 variables;
3. However, the zero set of any real quadratic polynomial can be represented as a determinant by taking a power of the polynomial.

This means I should be able to represent $g(\mathbf{x})=0$ as a determinantal equation by considering $\left( g(\mathbf{x}) \right)^n = 0$. The representation is based on Clifford algebras and concretely makes use of Weyl-Brauer matrices. This approach could be considered a principled way to arrive at a representation.